# JavaScript: capturing events regardless of element

Tags: javascript, events, dom

1. Is there any existing mechanism by which I can add an event listener to 'focus' for all the DOM elements on the page that have this event? If not, how might I do that?
2. I'd like to console.log(something) any time any DOM element fires an event. How might I do this?

**EDIT: Without any framework please :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the event to the body or html element. Or any other element which encloses all of your html.

Or if you want to use jQuery you could do something like

```
$("*").bind("focus", function(e){
    console.log("something");
})
```

Comment: Right you could do $(document) but the OP did not specify his need. I know $("*") is much slower but it almost sounded like he needed to do logging on element specific basis.

Answer (score 0):

Events "bubble" up through the DOM, so you should be able to bind a listener to document, body, html, or any other parent element (e.g. a div) and listen for every event triggered by elements that it contains.

For example, using JQuery, you could do it like this:

```
$(document).bind('focus', function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

This will log every focus event, no matter what element initially triggers the event.

Comment: ... unless the bubble gets cancelled.

Comment: The problem with this assertion is that certain events (`onfocus` being one of them) don't bubble (in IE). You can't generalize. Each event is special.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `:input` pseudo selector in jQuery.

```
$(':input').focus(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

This will only attach to the input elements which is probably what you're looking for anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (with jQuery).

```
$("input").focus(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Here's a live example:
http://jsbin.com/ipiciz/edit#javascript,html,live